# Smalltalk-style method browsing for eclipse Java?

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclipse (Indigo) for Java development. My personal, idiosyncratic style prefers to see Java methods one-at-a-time, instead and not as a region of a longer .java file.

I am looking for a preference, view, or plug-in that shows me a java method, and only that method, when I select the method name from a explorer or browser. For reference, here is a screen-shot of a typical Smalltalk browser (Cincom's VisualWorks). The "Method Code Area" shows on only one methods as opposed scrolling through all methods in the class.

[image: Cincom VisualWorkds System Broswer]

Answer (score 0):

The Java Browsing Perspective comes close to a Smalltalk browser. I customized it a little bit and found it very useful.

[image: Java Browsing Perspective]

Enable 'Show Source of Selected Element Only' and you will see only the selected method.

On today's widescreens, you won't need the whole width for the method source, and projects and methods take some vertical space. So I decided to vary the original Smalltalk layout.

Make sure that Eclipse closes open files automatically, as you want to browse, not to open and close files.

[image: Configure Close Editors Automatically]

One thing that is missing is the 'Protocol' view. Maybe the developers had something like that in mind while introducing the `@category` Javadoc tag, but the only thing you can do is to filter by category. I hope that some lucky day someone will develop a protocol view.

[image: Filter Categories]